# Resources not viewable in IDE but runs OK

Tags: c#, winforms, embedded-resource

Functionality being copied from project A  to project B.
The functionality is contained in 3 forms which are in an inheritance hierarchy. i.e. base form is inherited by intermediate form which is inherited by the top form.

In Project B, when the Top Form is displayed in the IDE in design mode, it shows the canvas of the intermediate form. (The properties side bar knows it is the top form but only shows the properties of the intermediate form)

Project B builds and runs  fine, showing the Top form canvas and interacting correctly.

In project A the Top Form displays correctly in design mode.

I took the resx files across and since the project is working I assume they are being found.

Same dev machine, both projects in same version of Visual studio (VS2013)

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

90% of the time when I have an issue with WinForms and the designer, it is solved by first cleaning the solution and then rebuilding it.  Not sure if you've tried that or not.

Comment: Hi John. Tried Clean, no joy. Created a new form, inherited from the same base form and it displays its own canvas. Go figure. So I am going to move the top form functionality over to the new form. Another one of life's little mysteries. Thanks, Bob